Load image to docker without dockerd
I want to load docker image without dockerd. (like docker load -i image.tar  )
I see that when I load docker image there are files that added to only 2 directories: overlay2,image
How can I set the desire files there from my image.tar without running docker/dockerd?
(I just want to understand the Docker filesystem layout. So I looking for a way to simulate the loading image in a shell script)

I... Really don't understand what you're hoping to achieve here, and strongly suspect you're dealing with an XY Problem. Can you try to reword?

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI I just want to understand the Docker filesystem layout. So I looking for a way to simulate the loading image in shell script
